# How to extract one number from a string

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract the last number (the price) from these strings:

```
"1  601 15.01.2019  14.01.2022  21.224,00"
"1  601 01.01.2019  31.12.2021  38.354,00"
"1  601 01.01.2019  31.12.2021  1629,32"
```

My pattern:

```
.Pattern = "\s\d{1,3}\.\d{3}"
```

The expected result:

```
21.224,00
38.354,00
1629,32
```

Comment: Which programming language are you using? It looks like the most suitable way for this would be something like a substring method that extracts the first character after the third space up until the last character of the string. You probably don't even need regex for this. You can even do a split on the whitespaces and take the 4th element.

Comment: What's the format of the number? Is comma required (every 3 digits)? If not, you could try https://regex101.com/r/IJC2es/1/

Comment: i try regex in VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this pattern: **`\d{1,2}\.?\d{3,4},\d{2}/gm`**.

See this demo: https://regex101.com/r/F45CmK/1

Comment: Thanks for a good job, "1 601 15.01.2019 14.01.2022 21.224,00"

"1 601 01.01.2019 31.12.2021 38.354,00"
"1 601 01.01.2019 31.12.2021 1629,32"
"1 601 25.03.2019 24.03.2022 48.073,00"
"1 601 01.04.2019 31.03.2020 420,00"
I modified the code a little bit and now it looks like this, thank you: \d{1,2}\.?\d{1,4},\d{2}